# Using MATLAB, how can I find the moving average?

Tags: matlab, matrix, append, convolution, moving-average

Using MATLAB, how can I find the 3-day moving average of a specific column of a matrix and append the moving average to that matrix?  I am trying to compute the 3-day moving average from bottom to top of the matrix.  I have provided my code:

Given the following matrix a and mask:

```
a = [1,2,3;4,5,6;7,8,9;10,11,12;13,14,15;16,17,18];
mask = ones(3,1);
```

I have tried implementing the conv command but I am receiving an error.  Here is the conv command I have been trying to use on the 2nd column of matrix a:

```
a(:,4) = conv(a(:,2),mask,'valid');
```

The output I desire is given in the following matrix:

```
desiredOutput = [1,2,3,5;4,5,6,8;7,8,9,11;10,11,12,14;13,14,15,0;16,17,18,0;]
```

If you have any suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.  Thank you!

Comment: Is `[1 1 1]` the convolution kernel for a moving average?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I figured that is the way to represent the 3-day moving average while invoking conv.

Comment: Your desired output does not look like a moving average. How are you getting these values?

Comment: For column 2 of matrix a, I am computing the 3-day moving average as follows and placing the result in column 4 of matrix a  (I renamed matrix a as 'desiredOutput' just for illustration).  The 3-day average of 17, 14, 11 is 14; the 3-day average of 14, 11, 8 is 11; the 3-day average of 11, 8, 5 is 8; and the 3-day average of 8, 5, 2 is 5.  There are no value in the bottom 2 rows for the 4th column because the computation for the 3-day moving average start at the bottom.  The 'valid' output will not be shown until at least 17, 14, and 11.  Hopefully this makes sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general it would help if you would show the error. In this case you are doing two things wrong:

First your convolution needs to be divided by three (or the length of the moving average)

```
c = conv(a(:,2),mask,'valid')/3

c =

     5
     8
    11
    14
```

Second, notice the size of `c`. You cannot just fit `c` into `a`. The typical way of getting a moving average would be to use `same`:

```
a(:,4) = conv(a(:,2),mask,'same')/3

a =

    1.0000    2.0000    3.0000    2.3333
    4.0000    5.0000    6.0000    5.0000
    7.0000    8.0000    9.0000    8.0000
   10.0000   11.0000   12.0000   11.0000
   13.0000   14.0000   15.0000   14.0000
   16.0000   17.0000   18.0000   10.3333
```

but that doesn't look like what you want.

Instead you are forced to use a couple of lines:

```
c = conv(a(:,2),mask,'valid')/3;
a(1:length(c),4) = c

a =

     1     2     3     5
     4     5     6     8
     7     8     9    11
    10    11    12    14
    13    14    15     0
    16    17    18     0
```

Comment: Perfect!  Thank you very much.  This is exactly what I was looking for so that I would not have to use loops.